# send data trough tcp with node js

Tags: node.js, tcp

I want to connect to a server with tcp connection and send data like this with nodejs and handle the response:

```
0000 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4A 96 70 27 C4 7A E5 51
0010 | 14 00 00 00 78 97 46 60 3E 05 49 82 8C CA 27 E9
0020 | 66 B3 01 A4 8F EC E2 FC
```

but I don't know how should I do this and I have no idea for this. what kind of data are these? and which package should I use to send these data? I have used `net` package but I didn't get any result.
I don't care how these data was created, I have these data as string.

Comment: use toString() on your data

Answer (score 0):

```js
const s = new net.Socket();
s.connect('url','port')
s.on('data',(data)=>{
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```